# How to import different CSV files into a single excel workbook using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have several distinct CSV files which all need to be imported into different sheets of an excel workbook. What is a convenient way to do this using c# ?

I have tried doing string operations on the CSV to extract each cells value and store it in the excel sheet cell by cell, but it becomes too computationally intensive.

Since I know importing a CSV manually into an excel sheet is quick, is there a good way to import the same programmatically?

Comment: just program it.

Comment: I have tried doing string operations on the CSV to extract each cells value and store it in the excel sheet cell by cell, but it becomes too computationally intensive.

Comment: Can you show to us what you've tried in terms of coding?